# C# Split string by characters ("-","_") and save the result

Tags: c#, string, split, save

I need to slip a string in c#.
The string looks like this:

```
string b = "aaaaa-bbbbb-ccccc_ddddd_eeeee";
```

I want to cut the string in 4 and save the aaaaa in one new string, the bbbbb in another new string, and so on till i have the aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,ddddd,eeeee in new string, all separated.
Example of wat i want in the end:

```
string a = "aaaaaaa";
string b = "bbbbbbb";
string a = "ccccccc";
string c = "ddddddd";
string e = "eeeeeee";
```

ps: i DONT want to store the strings in a array after they are split. I want to store them in NEW string variables.

Comment: Just use String.Split()

Comment: that doesnt awnser my question, i also want to safe the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use String.Split:

```
var items = b.Split(new char[] { '-', '_'} );
```

or Simply:

```
var items = b.Split( '-', '_' );
```

Here is full code:

```
string bb = "aaaaa-bbbbb-ccccc_ddddd_eeeee";
var items = bb.Split('-', '_');
string a = items[0];
string b = items[1];
string c = items[2];
string d = items[3];
string e = items[4];
```

Comment: use the `Split(params char[] separator)` overload `b.Split('-','_')`

Comment: and how do i save them after? like in the question?

Comment: well items will contain the split out chunks.. if you need to call them a,b,c etc you can do that manually after

Comment: @elmnt57 `items` is a string array, you can iterate through that.

Comment: @elmnt57 - `items` is a `string[]` see my edit.

Comment: thats what i wanted! much appreciated

Comment: @elmnt57 - you are welcome :)